# Local hosted HTML pages passing variable value

Tags: javascript

On page 1 I have a button with `onClick="window.location.href='Rendering.html?myVar1=3'"`
Then I am hoping to use the `myVar1` value here in page 2 (`Rendering.html`)  functions.

In page 2, I have:

```
var qs = new querystring();
var slideIndex = qs.get("myVar1")
showSlides(slideIndex);
```

However this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Function I found helpful:

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
  if (!url) url = window.location.href;
  name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
  var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
      results = regex.exec(url);

  if (!results) return null;
  if (!results[2]) return '';

  return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
```